# PHP & GD: Storing files created during session to then delete once session expires

Tags: php, session, gd, session-timeout

I am creating an online multi-layered GD image creation tool. Users can upload new images to the server to add to the GD produced image. I want to be able to store the gd image and all user uploaded files throughout the php session duration. The user can then choose to save these files permantly to their account but the default behaviour will be to delete the unused files after the session expires.

Does anyone have any pointers for me to explore?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I see 2 possibilities here.

1. Set a [custom session handler](http://www.php.net/manual/function.session-set-save-handler.php) which will define a garbage collection function to remove old images.
2. Another easy solution would be to use a CRON. You run it every 10 minutes and delete old images.

Disadvantage of the first solution will be that sometimes a user will get a longer load time because your garbage collection ran.

Disadvantage of the 2nd solution is you may not have access to this on a non-dedicated server.

You can also combine both solutions. I would probably do that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't get notified when a session expires. This just happens in the background. What you can do is have a task running in some sort of regular interval (let's say every hour) chat checks all files in the temporary directory and deletes all files that haven't been touched in a certain amount of time. [`filemtime()`](http://php.net/filemtime) is your friend here.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is pretty old already, but I am working on a similar project at the moment and wanted to share my solution as reference for others.

What I do is that I upload the image, convert it to base64 (**base64_encode()**) and then save it in a session variable, so I can delete the original images from the disk again.

When you want to make GD Operations with it, you need to grab the saved session data, decode it (**base64_decode()**) and create an image object (**imagecreatefromstring()**)

This is just a quick idea and it works for my application...

**Heads Up!**

base64-data can get a lot for big images, and the Session-Memory (memory_limit) is shared space with every other user on the page. So don't overdo this - because if a lot of people use your application at the same time, your memory_limit can exceed...